# Android TTS Service - How to?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, google-text-to-speech

I am working on an app that read out the incoming message to the user .When I click the start button on First Activity it starts the Speaker.java as a background service .While executing the app when I click the start button app stop's working then after 3-5 sec the service also unfortunately stops. I am new to service application.

Here's the Speaker.java

```
package com.texttospeech.test;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Speaker extends Service implements OnInitListener {
private TextToSpeech tts;

private boolean ready = false;

private boolean allowed = false;
private final int LONG_DURATION = 5000;
private final int SHORT_DURATION = 1200;
private BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver;
public Speaker(Context context){
    tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
}

public void allow(boolean allowed){
    this.allowed = allowed;
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        // Change this to match your
        // locale
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        ready = true;
    }else{
        ready = false;
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    initializeSMSReceiver();
    registerSMSReceiver();
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void speak(String text){

    // Speak only if the TTS is ready
    // and the user has allowed speech

    if(ready && allowed) {
        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
                String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, hash);
    }
}
public void pause(int duration){
    tts.playSilence(duration, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
}

private void initializeSMSReceiver(){
    smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(bundle!=null){
                Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
                    byte[] pdu = (byte[])pdus[i];
                    SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
                    String text = message.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    String sender = getContactName(message.getOriginatingAddress());
                    pause(LONG_DURATION);
                    speak("You have a new message from" + sender + "!");
                    pause(SHORT_DURATION);
                    speak(text);
                }
            }

        }
    };
}

private String getContactName(String phone){
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    String projection[] = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getString(0);
    }else {
        return "unknown number";
    }
}

private void registerSMSReceiver() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
    tts.shutdown();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

How to solve this to read incoming message always without launching the app.Thanks in advance.

Here's the Log

```
03/02 20:52:06: Launching app
$ adb push 
C:\Users\Manish\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.texttospeech.test
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.texttospeech.test"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.texttospeech.test
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 19262 on device micromax-micromax_a107-0123456789ABCDEF
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can 
be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/ActivityThread: BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{bf959e4 com.texttospeech.test}}
V/ActivityThread: Handling launch of ActivityRecord{3ce6ee4d token=android.os.BinderProxy@277d1d02 {com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity}}
V/ActivityThread: ActivityRecord{3ce6ee4d token=android.os.BinderProxy@277d1d02 {com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@28e43050, appName=com.texttospeech.test, pkg=com.texttospeech.test, comp={com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity}, dir=/data/app/com.texttospeech.test-2/base.apk
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/SettingsInterface: invalidate [secure]: current 3 != cached 0
D/ActivityThread: hoder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@3c7eeb55,provider,holder.Provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@67c496a
I/TextToSpeech: Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
V/ActivityThread: Performing resume of ActivityRecord{3ce6ee4d token=android.os.BinderProxy@277d1d02 {com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity}} finished=false
D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{3ce6ee4d token=android.os.BinderProxy@277d1d02 {com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity}}
V/ActivityThread: Resume ActivityRecord{3ce6ee4d token=android.os.BinderProxy@277d1d02 {com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{364017c I.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
D/OpenGLRenderer: initialize DisplayEventReceiver 0xb7fb9680
D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: false
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb803fb78) (w:768 h:768 s:768 f:0x1 u:0x000100)
D/Atlas: Validating map...
V/ActivityThread: Resuming ActivityRecord{3ce6ee4d token=android.os.BinderProxy@277d1d02 {com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity}} with isForward=true
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{1b8fe7d1 com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{364017c V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
V/ActivityThread: Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{3ce6ee4d token=android.os.BinderProxy@277d1d02 {com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity}}
D/ActivityThread: ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{3ce6ee4d token=android.os.BinderProxy@277d1d02 {com.texttospeech.test/com.texttospeech.test.MainActivity}}
E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL]: disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (0/0x5/0x6/0x4)
E/[DRVB][EXT][UTIL]: disp_only_chk: DRVB CHECK DISP PROCESS DONE ! (480/854/1)
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
I/[MALI][Gralloc]: dlopen libsec_mem.so fail
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8076ea8) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
I/MaliEGL: [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8076ea8) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8077eb8) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
I/TextToSpeech: Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100
V/InputMethodManager: START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{364017c V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-480,854} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@28bcf4e6 controlFlags=#104
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8095060) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
I/TextToSpeech: Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
V/SettingsInterface: invalidate [system]: current 222 != cached 0
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8094b58) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb80a84f0) (w:480 h:854 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.texttospeech.test, PID: 19262
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.texttospeech.test.Speaker: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.texttospeech.test.Speaker has no zero argument constructor
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2883)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:162)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1495)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
               Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.texttospeech.test.Speaker has no zero argument constructor
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1563)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2880)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1495) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> []
                  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
                  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:510)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1561)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2880) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1495) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Here's the MainActivity

```
package com.texttospeech.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
private Button start , stop;
private Speaker speaker;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    speaker = new Speaker(this);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == start){
            speaker.allow(true);
            speaker.speak(getString(R.string.start_speaking));
            startService(new Intent(this, Speaker.class));
        }else if(v == stop){
            speaker.speak(getString(R.string.stop_speaking));
            speaker.allow(false);
            startService(new Intent(this,Speaker.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `The service unfortunately stops`. Does that mean it crashes? Can you post your log messages?

Comment: Can you post your activity code where you start or initialise this speaker service?

Comment: Post your error logs; otherwise no one will be able to help you

Comment: I posted the log and MainActivty code

Comment: I got the code from  https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/use-text-to-speech-on-android-to-read-out-incoming-messages--cms-22524 . It works well but it not a service that it works when the app is running

Comment: Thanks you guys for answering . I cleared the app crash by adding default constructor . I need to check the tts output

Answer (score 1):

As per TTS, for the 1st step, check the message text which should be less than 4000 character. If it exceeds, it doesn't work. In my case, this was the problem.

Comment: I got the code from here
     https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/use-text-to-speech-on-android-to-read-out-incoming-messages--cms-22524

But it not a service . It works when the app is running